# What is the proper word for "shortened" version of a novel/article?

Tags: single-word-requests

Often we see classic novels/articles that are modified to be shorter to be easier for specific people such as kids to read. What is the proper word for the "shortened" version? Is it "an abbreviated version"?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46282/discussion-on-question-by-xuhdev-what-is-the-proper-word-for-shortened-version).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A literary work which has been shortened without losing the overall plot is said to be [abridged](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/abridge).

The Reader's Digest organisation used to produce books like this and call them "condensed" but what they were really doing was "abridging" them.

["Abbreviate"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/abbreviate) is a close synonym of "abridge" in some ways but would tend to be used for shorter pieces of text or, possibly, to a version that did not tell the whole story. For example many children's versions of Gulliver's travels only include the voyages to Lilliput and Brobdingnag and ignore the later voyages.